# Creating Vector with Condition

Tags: arrays, r, vector

How can I create this kind of array in R?

```
iii <- seq(from = 1, to = 49, by = 2)
```

this only creates values:

```
1  3  5 .. 49
```

The array that I need to create:

```
1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, . . . , 0, 49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
x <- 1:11
x * (x %% 2)
```

gives:

> ```
> [1]  1  0  3  0  5  0  7  0  9  0 11
> ```

What this does:

- `x %% 2` creates a vector of one's for the uneven values of `x` and zero's for the even values of `x`.
- Multiplying `x` with `x %% 2` thus gives a vector with uneven values with zero's in between.

---

Based the suggestion of @lmo, you could also do:

```
x <- seq(1, 11, 2)
head(rep(x, each = 2) * (1:0), -1)
```

which will give the same result.

Comment: @lmo nice alternative! you need to remove the last value though to get the desired result (see the update)

Comment: @ lmo true & fixed